# Calibrate touchscreen over xfce4

Tags: x11, touchscreen, xfce, xinput

dear experts
I have a problem with calibrating my Penmount touchscreen over x-server.
I connected through tslib.
In X, I have a compiled xf86-input-tslib library.
Unfortunately, ts_calibrate not working with "Illegal instruction level
Touch work good, the response from it is well, but sometimes, tap occurs on the wrong spot on a screen, sometimes with a deviance.
I try to calibrate screen with xinput-calibrator, but have no touchscreen in xinput -list:

```
xinput-calibrator
No calibratable devices found

mc ~ # DISPLAY=:0 xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Mouse1 id=6 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Keyboard1 id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

although in kernel:

```
mc ~ # dmesg | grep PenMount<br/>
input: PenMount Serial TouchScreen as 
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:02.2/tty/ttyS0/serio0/input/input3

mc ~ # cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=0013 Vendor=0031 Product=9000 Version=01f2
N: Name=«PenMount Serial TouchScreen»
P: Phys=ttyS0/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:02.2/tty/ttyS0/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event3
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
```

In Xorg.0.log i found this:

```
[1051910.230] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PenMount Serial >TouchScreen(/dev/input/event3)
[1051910.230] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[1051910.232] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PenMount Serial TouchScreen (/dev/input/mouse0)
[1051910.232] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[1051910.237] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ltc2954 (/dev/input/event2)
[1051910.237] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
```

What can I do for touch will appear in xinput --list?
Debain,  kernel 3.14

Answer (score 0):

What version of xf86-input-tslib and tslib did you use? Using xf86-input-tslib 1.1.1 and tslib 1.13 should actually work. In case you want to run ts_calibrate *while* running a graphical desktop, consider building tslib yourself, using `./configure --with-sdl2`